# Header background width css bug

Tags: bug, design

There is a bug in the global SE CSS.  If your browser window gets smaller than 982px, the container div that holds #header continues to shrink even though #header maintains a width of 962px.  The result is a background that doesn't quite reach all the way across the content.

[image]

The good news is that this bug is present on all sites (officials, metas and betas) and is cross-browser compliant and renders the same result in Chrome 17, IE 9, Safari 5, FF 10, and Opera 11 (all on Win 7) so you get high marks for consistency.

Potential fix:  add "min-width:982px;" to .container in all.css

Comment: Closed as "not a real issue": [everyone keeps all their app windows maximized now](http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/full-screen.html).

Comment: @CodyGray Your link is to a company that has seen recent popularity largely due to its polish at the presentation layer.  Polish is the result of fixing all the little things that are trivial on their own.    SE shouldn't be any different, especially when the fix appears to be equally trivial to implement.

Comment: @Farray Agreed, but you're saying this to a company that refuses to [pluralize words properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694) :)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Hm....  that must be especially vexing on http://english.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

They would need to add the style to `#custom-header` instead of `.container`, as the Stack Exchange header bar does not live within `.container`.

For some more consistency, I'd do `body > div, body > noscript { min-width: 982px; }` instead.

But this seems so trivial that it's probably not worth it. Even most netbooks these days have a wide enough screen width for Stack Exchange.