# Grammatical ambiguity with Chat's Starred Post UI

Tags: feature-request, chat, user-interface, wording, chat-stars

And no, it's not [a pluralization "bug"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694).

Consider the UI enclosed in the red hand-drawn circle:

[image]

The above image was captured from https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/10/loungec/?tab=stars

When I clicked on the orange "by me" link I was expecting to get all the posts I've written that have at least one star. Instead, I get a list of all posts that *I've* starred.

I read the above as "Starred posts by me", which to me meant "Posts that I've written that have at least one star". "Posts by me" can imply authorship the same way "books by me" or "books by Herb Sutter" implies authorship. I didn't think it meant "Posts that were starred by me" when I read it. Hence, the ambiguity.

With that interpretation, the "by everyone" link is also inaccurate, since there isn't a single post on Chat that *everyone* has starred.

As a result, the labeling is somewhat unintuitive and doesn't best reflect what each one does. At best, it is ambiguous.

Because of the English language's terrible syntax, I propose that the UI should say something like:

> **All starred posts** | **Posts that I've starred**

to better reflect what I actually get, or instead implement functionality that would allow me to see all posts I've written that has been starred by other people.

Comment: Actually I think this is grammatically correct - "Posts that were starred **by me**".

Comment: @Lix: I sure didn't read it like that. I read "Starred posts by me" to mean "Posts *that I've written* that have at least one star". "Posts by me" could mean "Posts I've written" the same way as "books by me" or "books by Herb Sutter" implies authorship. I didn't think it meant "Posts that were starred by me" when I read it. Hence, the ambiguity.

Comment: Ahh!! *Now* it sounds funny to me too :P

Answer (score 2):

Personally when reading that *in conjunction with the title directly above it* I don't see any ambiguity.  The behaviour is just what I would expect when looking for posts starred 'by me'. Also I think that the combination of the header with the filters is more effective than the new filter text you suggested, which would presumably render the title obsolete so result in its removal?

Comment: I did read it in conjunction with the title. I read "Starred posts by me" and the "by me" part to me means "I wrote these posts". But that's not what I get when I click on the "by me" link.