# Pluralization bug in chat transcript only

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, plurals

In a normal chat session, time lapses between messages will be represented like so:

[image: Normal chat session; no pluralization bug]

But in the transcript of the same thing (pixel-perfect, this is the same image except for the pluralization bug (which I'm about to mention)), there's a pluralization bug (freehand circle mine):

[image: Chat transcript; pluralization bug! :O]

This is a serious issue and needs to be fixed post-haste. I'm counting on you, dev team!

Comment: Beware [the 'S'](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694)!

Comment: @IuliusCæsar: Yes, yes. Been there, done that already. But now I have permission to try.

Comment: Lemmie get right on that one :)

Comment: I hear Shog9 has taken control of the almighty S.

Comment: "So wait more than one hour."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We has checked in a fixes for these bug.

Comment: Wait, we're fixing pluralization bugs now?  This is insane!  Hans!

Comment: Wow, less than six to eight weeks! That's awesome! Thanks.

Comment: Must...not...edit...out...joke...