# "Number of votes" on questions versus "question score"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, question-lists

> Related question: [Is negative one plural?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165244/is-negative-one-plural)

List of questions on any of the SE sites (let's say SO for the sake of the argument) contains the "number of votes" (the best interpretation I infer from the listing itself) - see this screenshot or random couple of questions:

[image]

The issue is that this "number" is not really the number of votes - but the number of upvotes minus the number of downvotes.  Hence any question that is displayed with "0 votes" could in reality have +10 and -10 (10 upvotes and 10 downvotes).  Furthermore, any question with more downvotes than upvotes will show as the negative number of votes, which doesn't really make sense.

While this value is useful on a listing, wouldn't it make more sense to call it something else? For example, "score -1" is a better indication of what that value really means than "-1 votes".

Comment: Good point, +1.

Comment: I knew this topic [sounded familiar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165244/is-negative-one-plural#comment482349_165245). ;)