# Pluralization bug in the network profile

Tags: bug, network-profile, plurals, grammar

This image says it all:

[image: Screenshot of the "accounts" tab of the network profile page with "1 badges" and "1 questions" stat items]

As you can see, I'm viewing someone's network profile and it says "1 question**s**". The same problem goes with the answers, but you don't see that in the image because the user didn't post precisely one answer.

The badges also have a pluralization bug because it's saying:

> 1 bronze badge**s**

So I think the "**s**" needs to go away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this one is less problematic than others, because the layout is different.

In your case, the pluralized word is placed *under* the number, not *right after* the number. This makes interpretation different, like:

- 1 question**s**
- Number of question**s**: 1

Obviously the first one is an error, but the second one is perfectly valid.

For example, here's a page from Google Analytics:

> [image]

Same look.

Comment: Oh! But the question part is still rather confusing because the word 'questions' is *under* the number, therefore, I read it like "1 questions." Thanks!

Comment: Then we should at least make all such lists consistent. The [list of posts on your user page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EN8A2.png) has the same layout, yet it is pluralized differently. I don’t really have a preference for either pluralization rule, provided the word is _under_ the number. Of course, there’s _also_ still the [problem of “votes” not actually counting the number of votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186552/289905).