# Pluralization 'Bug' in flag summary page: 1 answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, tooltips, flag-history, plurals

Now that Jeff and [his giant S](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694/152859) are safely away,  I feel safe to report that in the flag summary page when there is a flagged question with exactly one answer, it shows:

> [image]

Picky, I know! But it hurts my eyes. :-)

Comment: *Jeff Atwood: seen 2 hours ago* ... twas nice knowing you.

Comment: @Bart but he's on his own now so I'm not afraid. :-D

Comment: `Typo on line 1: "Not" should be "Now"`.

Comment: https://mobile.twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105

Comment: @Nick I took safety measures, no worry! ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd You notice he still has a Diamond? That means he can still do things to you.

Comment: @Undo yup, but much less than before when he owned the place! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This got fixed ... *not sure when* :)

Recent screenshot:

> [image]

Comment: Yup, that's true. :)