# Guys? 1 years is back!

Tags: bug, grammar, plurals

Yes, I know that this is a pluralization bug. I have purchased enormous locks for my doors and am currently inside a box made of high-quality woven waffles (a waffle box!), guarded by an army of unicorns - I'm fully protected against all bludgeoning attempts.

---

I have noticed something disturbing on the user profile page - specifically that [this user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/187824/hims056) has apparently been a member for 1 years, 2 months:

[image]

I could have sworn that this used to say 1 year, but it seems to have been borked. Could we <s>fix</s> *improve the grammatical quality of* this?

Comment: You might need a box stronger than iron.

Comment: Got any suggestions?

Comment: maybe one guarded by an army of unicorns

Comment: How's that look?

Comment: Just missing a freehand circle ;-)

Comment: What am I supposed to be looking at in your screenshot? If only there was a circle to point me at the problem.

Comment: I love this site because of this ^

Comment: HEY LOOK IT'S A PLURALIZATION BUG. [_Are you ready to die?_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694)

Comment: @Undo last off-topic comment - but you misspelled EEEEEK

Comment: @Undo ok one more.... OH DEAR GOD, I have been a member for 1 years 5 months.  I am part of the problem,

Comment: @psubsee2003 that's a dialect. Russian, I think.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Aaak is the new Eeek.

Comment: @Emrakul Even Atwood himself wouldn't even think of trying to penetrate a waffle box.

Comment: Was this ME? I've been a member of MSO for 1 years 2 months as well, apparently! :)

Comment: [Jeff Atwood's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Atwood) *Big-S* is an official meme: [Pluralization Bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/63791#63791) (from [The Many Memes of Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478)).