# Typo in hovertext on /tags/synonyms

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling, plurals

On https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms (and presumably all other `/tags/synonyms` pages on other SE sites; it's certainly present on SO/SU/SF), when you hover over the "active" button (which takes you to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=active&tab=newest), the following text is displayed as hovertext:

> Only active tag synonym

On grammatical grounds, this should be:

> Only active tag synonym**s**

Comment: Watch out for the [giant S](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694/223030)...

Comment: A bug is a bug, whether Jeff (who no longer even works for Stack Exchange) likes it or not.

Comment: sharp eye, tnx. fixing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another bug introduced during our i18n efforts. Fix will be out in the next build, rev `2013.11.11.1623` on meta and `2013.11.11.1145` on sites.