# Pluralization bug in unicoin sidebar!!!11!!1eleven

Tags: bug, april-fools, unicoins, plurals

I have one Unicoin.  Only, the sidebar keeps telling me I have "1 Unicoin**s**".

[image: Here it is!]

This needs to be fixed ASAP!

Comment: Beware the big S.

Comment: Dat new tag... :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"Unicoins" is a [plurale tantum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurale_tantum). The fact that it ends in "s" is pure coincidence.

Comment: Then shouldn't [tag:status-by-design] be added to the question? :P

Answer (score 26):

I have to [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) this.

There is an easy workaround: all you have to do is  <s>slave away in the coin mines</s> be rich.

Comment: Better suggestion: when a user has exactly 1 Unicoins make it 0. Problem solved. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Aha! And then you'll sneak in some code to route all those extra single Unicoins into your account, and retire strinking rich, right? But I've seen through your scheme! You won't get away with it that easily, oh no you won't... Of course, if we were to come to a suitable *\*ahem\** mutual understanding, this comment just might conveniently disappear... if you know what I mean. ;-)

Comment: Jeff! Where is Jeff! [He promised](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694/171199). :P Bring on the Gigas S mace! ^_^

Comment: … why didn't you add the status tag?

Comment: @bjb568 ... why do you even care. Old April Fools post is old. Also something something jokes.

Comment: IT NEED TAAAAAAG! How else are we supposed to know at a glance that it's declined?

Comment: @bjb568 It's closed. :P

Comment: You can still edit it. Come on, *you know you want to*…

Answer (score 19):

### Pluralization bug in question about pluralization bug in unicoin sidebar!!!11!!1eleven

There is only one extra S. Only, the question keeps telling me it has "EXTRA***S***".

[image]

This needs to be fixed ASAP!