# TIL: the singular of Unicoins is Unicoins

Tags: discussion, unicoins, april-fools

I saw this on my home page just now.

[image]

In case I have misread it, I zoomed in to see the letters more clearly, only to discover that the singular of Unicoins *is* Unicoins.

[image]

I doubt this is not a grammar bug because Unicoins are/is a mythical monetary unit and it has power so mythological that I am still trying to comprehend.

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO why why why you didn't tag this "Bug". I really wanted to see the ["Ancient Giant S of Jeff Wrath" legendary mace](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694/171199) again!