# "1 new items in your Stack Exchange inbox"

Tags: bug, email, email-notification, plurals

Notification emails from Stack Exchange say:

> 1 new item**s** in your Stack Exchange inbox

If you have only 1 new item, that should be "1 new **item**", singular.

Comment: [Obligatory warning](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694/).

Comment: [Does this make you nervous?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cMoFi.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for posting here, sorry I didn't know it was a duplicate.