# Pluralization issue in Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, plurals

When I try to vote too fast, I get a message saying:

> You cannot perform this action for another **1 seconds**

(Emphasis mine.)

[image: Screenshot]

Stack Exchange app version 1.0.51.

Comment: Are you sure you want to keep this question up? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694

Comment: *beats with giant S*

Comment: Well, fortunately in Android, [it's possible to do that easily with String resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#Plurals), but I agree we have to beat OP with giant S ;)

Comment: @AndrewT. sadly this error is coming from the API call, so we can't use string resources.

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed in the next API build.