# 1 bounty is very bounty

Tags: discussion, plurals, active-bounties

When you have only 1 bounty, the bounty shows up as

> 1 bounties

[image]

Am I interpreting it right? As in I have participated in 1 bounty? Or is this a grammar error? Please explain.

<sub>Sorry Jeff, don't kill me [with your 'S'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/63791#63791)</sub>

Comment: To repeat 'who cares?'

Comment: @santiago I care because I can't stand to see it

Comment: May be you should reword the question and ask it differently e.g. how should one read/interpret the "1" displayed in blue background next to "bounties"... I think that may help you to reverse the downvotes. And, I did not DV you as I see some users would read it like what you said.

Comment: +1 That's a good rewording except some DV's may not like the WARNING part... BTW, where can I find the post/info about Jeff's "don't kill me with your 'S'"

Comment: @HackerKarma [Here you go!](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105)

Comment: Link is broken... shows me blank page

Comment: @HackerKarma Its Jeff Atwood's twitter, it shouldn't be blank

Comment: I see your edited the comment... it's working now. Thanks. BTW, I just did a search on the "bludgeon" keyword and found the Jeff's post where he talks about the tweet: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694

Comment: Thanks for the removing "WARNING" statement... now lets hope all those downvoters come back and reverse their votes. We're all learning here. I wonder if they get any sort of notifications for the update made on the post

Comment: Downvote converted to upvote. More-so because you changed "bug" to "discussion", and I disagreed with it being a bug or problem. As a discussion, I have no problems you asking such things :) The wording was a little "abrupt" too, uppercase makes you seem shouty/angry ;)

Comment: @UnicornsAreVeryVeryYummy Hey, its working... DVs are now turning into UPs. Now your question is turning into a nice discussion. Already 3 answers with a different views and could possibly more....

Answer (score 12):

> Am I interpreting it right? As in I have participated in 1 bounty? Or
>   is this a grammar error?

In that specific area, it states "[1] bounties" and not "[1] bounty" because the word "bounties" is a fixed name to identify the profile area you can go to which is all about "bounties".
And the [1] is just a *system indication* of the number of "bounties" you currently have active for that area of your profile, and the two are separate and do not form a readable sentence or word pair.

e.g.

> The "bounties" area has "[1] active" item in it.

---

In the same way that all of the other tabs in that area are plural:

> summary | answers | questions | tags | badges | favorites | bounties |
>   reputation | all actions | responses | votes

(Apart from "reputation" but that is obviously correct as a singular entity.)

When I have a single (1) response, it still shows:

> [1] responses

Because the "responses" area has "1 active item".

### That said

I don't think it matters because the two do not form a sentence and aren't *technically supposed to* form a readable pair.
But I can see why users (including yourself) would read it like that.

I don't think it's worth changing at all, as per my above answer details, but if there was to be a change, the simple solution would be to put the number after the word.

> bounties [1]
>   bounties [3]

But given the system has been like that for donkey's years I don't think it's a worthwhile change, users are familiar with the count being before the word.

Comment: +1 for the details and covering many aspects.

Answer (score 5):

That is a tab in your Activity page isn't it?

That tab is supposed to be read as "bounties" forever until some future change pops up. The number just shows you how many ***bounties*** you have. When reading that, most people think of: How many bounties do this user have? Hence reasoning and logic for the plural noun.

Anyways, it literally says:

> 1 active ***bounty*** for 50 reputation.

Comment: But when it shows `1` in bracket it should know that it is singular..

Comment: The 1 in the blue square is right next to the name of the tab, which can't be changed until approved.

Comment: Blue background highlight is very important otherwise the meaning gets changed

Answer (score 4):

Also, if you notice, the **bounties** tooltip message says:

> bounties this user has participated in

alternatively it can be read as:

> *number* of bounties this user has participated in

So in this case, it becomes like:

> *number* of bounties this user has participated in: 1