# It's been 1 days since you asked your last question

Tags: bug, questions, grammar, plurals

There is a bug when you need to take a break from questions. It says

> It's been 1 day**s** since you asked your last question.

And I am personally ticked off when there is bad grammar on a website of all things.

So maybe make an algorithm that checks if it is one, set it to days?

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694