# Pluralization bug when editing a comment: "Too long by 1 characters"

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, plurals, comment-edits

I found a pluralization bug, which I reproduced on Meta Ask Ubuntu and Meta SE (and probably other places, but that is where I tried it). "Too long by 1 characters" is wrong. It should be "Too long by one character". Oh, and [please don't bludgeon me with a giant S](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694/1081494) :)

Here's a screenshot of the issue. I tested it on Ask Ubuntu Meta and [in the formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox#comment1238251_3122).
[image: Screenshot of bug]

Summary: in the comment edit box, when edit would be too long by one character, it says "Too long by 1 characters", plural. That is incorrect.

Comment: That meme has [officially been deprecated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/1017231), so you don't have to worry.

Comment: In other words, `Too long by 1 characters` is too long by 1 character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All fixed now!

> [image: Too long by one character]